# Помогите разобраться с градиентом CSS

Tags: html, css, градиент

```
html {
  background: 
     linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 37%, #dde 0, #dde 63%, transparent 0), 
              #8B4513;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

Вот есть такой градиент. Путем различных изменений % у transparent и цвета #dde так и не понял по-какому принципу это строится. Был бы признателен, если бы кто-то смог это объяснить :)

Comment: Линейный градиент http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/lineinyi-gradient

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/34cb031.png

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Спасибо большое!